# Can i delete the elements of my datagrid without changing the datasource?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datasource

I want to delete the element of my datagrid without changing my datasource.

When I choose to bind my datagrid to my database Test, it works.
My datagrid shows my 2 columns : "ID" and "Name" with the specific rows.
I can add row to my datagrid and save it to my database.

But now I want to show the name of the columns without any elements, so the user can add rows without seeing the elements of my database.

How can I do this?

Comment: As is [required on this website](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please show your code attempt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest, Create a ObservableCollection of Type Custom Class in which you will have IsVisible property. By default value is false and you can add logic in the xaml if IsVisible = false then hide that row from the grid.

```
public ObservableCollection<GridInfo> Data { get; set; }

public class GridInfo
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; } 
    // other properties will come like this
}
```

In the XAML you can use converter with the Visibility property of your grid row like below.

```
Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
```

And you will have the converter like below:

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visibility = !(bool)value;
        return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
        return (visibility == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood the question. The question author said *But now I want to show the name of the columns without any elements, so the user can add rows without seeing the elements of my database*... nothing about hiding rows.

Comment: Without seeing the element means user want to hide the data from the outer world and don't want to delete the actual data (as per the user, he wants to delete the data from the grid and not from the datasource).

Comment: If you read their question again (which I accept is *not* clear), I think that you'll find that they just want to show an empty row: *so the user can add rows without seeing the elements of my database*. Either way, we'll find out soon enough.

Comment: Why MxR answer is down voted? It's a preety good solution according to the requirement. If you don't hide the rows then whenever user enters its first record, it will show in the grid. So need to hide the rows.

Comment: I down voted it because I think that he understood the question wrong... if the question author ever returns and disagrees, then I will happily remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the DataSource of your DataGrid to a property of the type

```
ObservableCollection<T>
```

This way the data source gets notified whenever the collection changes.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are correctly `Binding` to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property, all you need to do to add a new empty row is to add a new item to your data bound collection:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />

...

Items.Add(new YourItemtype());
```

If you are *not* correctly `Binding` with the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property, then *that* is what you need to do. Create a property of the type of your data type:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourItemtype> Items { get; set; }
```

And of course, make sure that you set your `DataContext` to the correct data source that contains the property.